# database.setValue(value) opens a new screen of the same activity

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

First I am working in kotlin.

I am having a frustrating issue with setting values in firebase.

I am using itemTouchHelper for actions. When you swipe right I need it to set a value in firebaseDatabase.

the code I am using for this is:

```
responseDatabase.child(requestedUserUid!!).child("response").child(uid).child(selectedPath).setValue(i)
```

i is a custom object. `requestedUserUid!!` is a nullable string of another users UID. uid is the users UID.

When the `setValue` is called it opens a blank copy of the activity on top of the stack.

I have narrowed it down to this single line of code causing this issue. If I do not include that line the app works perfectly.

The app does not crash and the only thing in the logcat that I can find is:

> handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@6c3f9f0

I am not sure if it is related.

any answers or even just a point in the right direction would be appreciated.

I have tried moving it to a separate function, changing it to an `asyncTask`, and setting the objects values as separate strings.

The libraries I am using are:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'


    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.5'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.5'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.startapp:inapp-sdk:4.6.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.9.0'
```

Logcat:

```
2020-07-18 08:21:25.936 17650-17650/com.jeremykruid.dyner W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@da1b4
2020-07-18 08:21:26.146 17650-17711/com.jeremykruid.dyner D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe061a360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe060f500)
2020-07-18 08:21:26.371 17650-17711/com.jeremykruid.dyner D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe061a360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe060f500)
2020-07-18 08:21:26.385 17650-17650/com.jeremykruid.dyner E/StartAppSDK: Failed to load BANNER ad: Ad wasn't loaded: serving ads disabled
2020-07-18 08:21:26.404 17650-17711/com.jeremykruid.dyner D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe061a360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe060f500)
```

Comment: It sounds like your app crashes on the call to `setValue` and is then auto-restarted by Android. If that is the case, there'll be an error message and stack trace in the logcat output. Please find those and add them to your question.

Comment: This is all that comes on the logcat